# how to extract log data of accelerometer values into a file from eclipse?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, logging, extract

I have created an app which is in java android. Now, I need to test my app which is based on accelerometer values and i need to store accelerometer values into a text file for later evaluation. I know that i need to change some permission into my manifest file but i don't know how should i store all the values when my phone is not connected with laptop via cable. Logcat only gives log data for about 2 mins. I am using nexus 5 for testing.
How can i solve this problem? Do i need to give root access to my phone?

Comment: I´d recomend log to external file http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html

Comment: Thank you eduyayo but will this work when the cable is not attached to the phone and laptop?

Comment: you´ll be writing to your device external storage... after you plug the device to your computer again, you can copy the data file from it.

Comment: Ok.. Thanks alot for your valuable comment.